# Okta not staying logged in on IE

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, internet-explorer-11, okta

I have an asp.net 4.7 app and am trying to integrate Okta single sign-on. I have it logging in and authenticating correctly, and it works fine in Chrome, but on IE11 whenever I go to my login page it always thinks it is a new user, ie. a session doesn't exist.

```
oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
        baseUrl: "<%= Application["ssoBaseUrl"]%>",
        clientId: "<%= Application["ssoClientId"]%>",
        redirectUri: "<%= Application["ssoRedirectUri"]%>",
        authParams: {
            issuer: "<%= Application["ssoIssuer"]%>",
            responseType: ['token', 'id_token'],
            display: 'page',
        }
    });
    if (oktaSignIn.token.hasTokensInUrl()) {
        oktaSignIn.token.parseTokensFromUrl(
            function success(res) {
                //user tokenManager
            },
            function error(err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        oktaSignIn.session.get(function (res) {
            if (res.status === 'ACTIVE') { //User logged in
                SSOSetup(res.login);
                return;
            }
            else { //No user logged in
                oktaSignIn.renderEl(
                    { el: '#okta-login-container' },
                    function success(res) {
                        if (res.status == "SUCCESS") {
                            return;
                        }
                    },
                    function error(err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

Every time I go to my login page, even right after logging in, it goes to the 'no user logged in' branch, ie. res.status !== "ACTIVE". It usually is either empty or "INACTIVE", yet in Chrome it always works as expected.

How can I fix my SSO on IE11 to stay logged in properly?

Development: I've narrowed it down to the fact that the REST request for the active session returns 200 for chrome and 404 for ie11. The cookie supplied in ie11 is much smaller than the one in chrome, which is weird considering I am using the same api code (literally just running the app of different browsers without changing anything).

Comment: Can you please inform us which Exact version of IE 11, OS build you are using for making this test? For testing purpose, try to add your site to trusted site list to check whether it helps anything or not. Try to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" /> in your web page. Check whether any new Windows updates are available or not. If available than install latest updates.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I tried making it a trusted site and adding that meta tag, neither changed the behavior. IE version: 11.678.17763.0, update version 11.0.140. I'm up to date on my updates.

Comment: I updated my Okta library (from 2.4-ish to 3.10), and after struggling through their terrible documentation the same behavior still happens. Once I log in on Chrome I stay logged in (and redirect automatically, like it should), but I have to log in to IE every time, which kind of defeats the whole point of using SSO.

Comment: Currently I am not available with any subscription of OKTA SSO to make a test with IE to reproduce the issue. If you are available with any subscription of OKTA SSO than you can try to contact their product support than give some idea to you.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Unfortunately I am a free user only, and their community forums are even less frequented than SO is.